# How to pair a list of lists in various ways based on the first element

Tags: python

I have a particular problem that I'm trying to solve and not having much luck.

It's quite difficult to explain fully but I have a list of lists that I'm generating through an intent detection algorithm I'm writing, I need to pair them together based on the first element of each of the sublists.

The list will be sorted so they will always be in order of lowest to highest, and essentially each number has a list of numbers to pair with. So if index[0][0] is 3, then pair with any 10, 11, 18, 19 or 20 - duplicating if necessary. And so on.

```
SUB_NOUNS = {
             3: [10, 11, 18, 19, 20],
             10: [22],
}
```

Here are some examples of my inputs and my desired outputs from them, explaining what I need to happen.

```
# For only 1 item leave unchanged
In: [[3, 1, 0]]
Out: [[3, 1, 0]]

# Second item is sub item of first item - so join.
In: [[3, 1, 0], [10, 2, 0]]
Out: [[3, 1, 0, 10, 2, 0]]

# Second and third item are sub items of first item, make two lists.
In: [[3, 2, 0], [10, 3, 0], [10, 4, 0]]
Out: [[3, 2, 0, 10, 3, 0], [3, 2, 0, 10, 4, 0]]

# Three items, no sub items - unchanged
In: [[3, 1, 0], [3, 2, 0], [3, 3, 0]]
Out: [[3, 1, 0], [3, 2, 0], [3, 3, 0]]

# Third item is sub item of second item which is sub item of first item - Join all
In: [[3, 2, 0], [10, 3, 0], [22, 12, 0]]
Out: [[3, 2, 0, 10, 3, 0, 22, 12, 0]]

# Third item is sub item of second and first item, make two lists.
In: [[3, 1, 0], [3, 2, 0], [18, 0, 0]]
Out: [[3, 1, 0, 18, 0, 0], [3, 2, 0, 18, 0, 0,]]
```

Hopefully I've explained this well enough, I'm not exactly looking for a perfect solution as there are other potential combinations that I haven't listed here but if someone could point me in the right direction I can probably figure it out from there.

Comment: In the example " Three items, no sub items - unchanged", `0` is common in 3 sub-lists, why still unchanged?

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri What matters is whether the first element in the later sublists is in the list that 3 maps to in the dictionary.

Comment: what if the first item is a sub-item of the second item? e.g. `[[10, 1, 2], [3, 4, 1]]`

Comment: How is `10, 2, 0` a sub item of `3, 1, 0` in the second example?

Comment: But anyway, what exactly is the programming difficulty you encountered while doing this task?

Comment: Yeah @barmar has got it, it's basically all down to the first items. Well everything I try just doesn't work, using for loops etc it just starts to get messy and unreadable. Wondering if this any way of doing this kind of thing. Maybe itertools or some other package, if someone could point me in the right direction I can probably work something out.

Comment: The only tricky thing is that you need to retain the first sublist if there are no matches, otherwise concatenate it with each of the matches.

Comment: I think I'm close to a solution - using itertools.dropwhile. I can't post an answer as the question is closed so I'll edit what I've got so far into the question maybe someone can help.

Comment: There seems to be another thing here: you only want to concatenate lists whose first item is increasing! (seen in `[3, 2, 0], [10, 3, 0], [10, 4, 0]`). I would recommend: 1. Try to put the rules in bullet points (to be more clear), 2. Provide runable example and 3. teak the input/examples if needed to cover more cases. This should make the question more clear in regards to what works and what not

Comment: OK - I think I have solved it using itertools. If someone will reopen the question I'll post the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a lot harder than it seems with a quick read!

That said, I have tried few things (cause it made me stubborn...) and I will present: (1) observations/questions, (2) a potential answer and (3) some comments on your original solution

Starting with a recap of requirements:

- You have a list of lists
- The sub-lists are ordered based on their first element
- You have a map, `SUB_NOUNS`, which tells us which lists can be followed by which others based on each list's first element
- You are looking for potential combinations

Observations (and maybe open questions):

- In the OP you are showing a SUB_NOUNS example with 2 entries. I am assuming that more than two entries are also possible
- In the example of `[[3, 2, 0], [10, 3, 0], [22, 12, 0]]` we see that you are looking for the **longest possible combo**, therefore:

  - Combinations can have 2+ levels (unbounded). This smells like "recursion" to me and that's how the proposed solution is
  - Altho `[10, 3, 0], [22, 12, 0]` (without the `[3, 2, 0]`) is a valid combination, you do not list it in the example output. This makes me assume that you do not want to reuse lists that you have already used in a longer combo as a  *starting* point of another combo
- In the example of `[[3, 1, 0], [3, 2, 0], [18, 0, 0]]`, based on the desired output we see that the same list can participate in multiple combos, as long as the "prefix" (the lists before it) are different

### Proposed Solution

As mentioned earlier, this is recursive and has two parts:

1. `get_all_combos` which gathers all the potential combinations for all the lists that can act as a starting point. This also controls list reuse (see later)
2. `get_combos`: The recursive part of the solution that forms all the combinations for a given starting list

(You can ignore or remove the logging, but is usually needed in recursion for debugging purposes...)

```
def get_all_combos(data, allow_reuse=False):
    """ For each element in the data list, find its combinations recursively"""
    all_combos = []
    all_used_lists = set()
    for item_num, item in enumerate(data):
        # Do not start new combinations from lists
        # that appear somewhere inside another combination
        if item_num in all_used_lists and not allow_reuse:
            continue

        combos, used = get_combos(data, item_num)
        if combos:
            all_combos.extend(combos)
            all_used_lists.update(used)

    return all_combos or data

def get_combos(data, list_num=0):
    """
    Return all combinations from list_num onwards and also the indexes
    of the lists that were used to form those combos
    """
    lg.debug(f"{list_num * 4 * ' '} list num: {list_num}")
    combos = []
    used_lists = set()
    current_list = data[list_num]
    current_first = current_list[0]

    # Filter all allowed pairs
    for pair_num, pair in enumerate(data[list_num + 1:], list_num + 1):
        # Skip elements that cannot be combined (we could also use filter())
        if pair[0] not in SUB_NOUNS[current_first]:
            continue

        lg.debug(f"{list_num * 4 * ' '} Pair_num {pair_num}")

        # Get combos of this pair
        subcombos, used = get_combos(data, pair_num)
        lg.debug(f"{list_num * 4 * ' '} Subcombos {subcombos}")

        # If there are no subcombinations, just combine the current list
        # with its child one (pair)
        if not subcombos:
            combos.append(current_list + pair)
            used_lists.update({list_num, pair_num})
            lg.debug(f"{list_num * 4 * ' '} Inserting {combos[0]}")
            continue

        # Here we have sub-combos. For each one of them, merge it to the
        # current combos
        for combo in subcombos:
            combos.append(current_list + combo)
            used_lists.update(used | {list_num})
            lg.debug(f"{list_num * 4 * ' '} Extending appends {combos[0]}")

    lg.debug(f"{list_num * 4 * ' '} Combos {combos}")
    lg.debug(f"{list_num * 4 * ' '} Used {used_lists}")
    return combos, used_lists
```

Now, before we go to look at some output of the above code, lets take a quick look at your solution (inline comments):

```
def pair_lists(data):
    pairs = []
    # > Reversal can be potentially avoided here
    for noun in reversed(data):
        try:
            # > Instead of itertool+filter false, you could just use filter() 
            # > with the reverse condition right?
            result = itertools.filterfalse(lambda x: x[0] not in SUB_NOUNS[noun[0]], data)
            for each in result:
                paired = []
                # > ^--- The following if is always false since paired is always [] 
                if each not in paired:
                    paired.insert(0, each)
                # > insert vs append depends on the reversal in the outer loop
                paired.insert(0, noun)
                pairs.append(list(itertools.chain(*paired)))
        except KeyError:
            pass
    return pairs if pairs else data
```

A more compact version which should be 100% the same logic is the following:

```
def pair_lists_urban(data):
    pairs = []
    for noun in data:
        try:
            result = filter(lambda x: x[0] in SUB_NOUNS[noun[0]], data)
            for each in result:
                pairs.append(noun + each)
        except KeyError:
            pass
    return pairs if pairs else data
```

Note that both the above versions have a contraint/issue: They look at only two levels of lists to form a combo (ie N and N+1). This will become apparent in the next section

### Tests

So, lets run all the solutions so far with the example lists that you provided. The main script is:

```
import itertools
import logging as lg
import sys


SUB_NOUNS = {
    3: [10, 11, 18, 19, 20],
    10: [22],
}


# ... funcs for each solution

test_lists = [
    [[3, 1, 0]],
    [[3, 1, 0], [10, 2, 0]],
    [[3, 2, 0], [10, 3, 0], [10, 4, 0]],
    [[3, 1, 0], [3, 2, 0], [3, 3, 0]],
    [[3, 2, 0], [10, 3, 0], [22, 12, 0]],
    [[3, 1, 0], [3, 2, 0], [18, 0, 0]],
]

for l in test_lists:
    print(f"\nIn: {l}")
    print(f"Recur Out: {get_all_combos(l)}")
    print(f"Iter. Out: {pair_lists(l)}")
    print(f"Iter2 Out: {pair_lists_urban(l)}")
```

Looking at the output, we have (with comments):

```
# All good 
In: [[3, 1, 0]]
Recur Out: [[3, 1, 0]]
Iter. Out: [[3, 1, 0]]
Iter2 Out: [[3, 1, 0]]

# All good 
In: [[3, 1, 0], [10, 2, 0]]
Recur Out: [[3, 1, 0, 10, 2, 0]]
Iter. Out: [[3, 1, 0, 10, 2, 0]]
Iter2 Out: [[3, 1, 0, 10, 2, 0]]

# All good 
In: [[3, 2, 0], [10, 3, 0], [10, 4, 0]]
Recur Out: [[3, 2, 0, 10, 3, 0], [3, 2, 0, 10, 4, 0]]
Iter. Out: [[3, 2, 0, 10, 3, 0], [3, 2, 0, 10, 4, 0]]
Iter2 Out: [[3, 2, 0, 10, 3, 0], [3, 2, 0, 10, 4, 0]]

# All good 
In: [[3, 1, 0], [3, 2, 0], [3, 3, 0]]
Recur Out: [[3, 1, 0], [3, 2, 0], [3, 3, 0]]
Iter. Out: [[3, 1, 0], [3, 2, 0], [3, 3, 0]]
Iter2 Out: [[3, 1, 0], [3, 2, 0], [3, 3, 0]]

# ! some issues: Recursion outputs the desired result while the other 
# two solutions do not. This is because as mentioned earlier, these 
# are only looking at two levels for each pair and that is also why
# resulting combos have only 6 elements
In: [[3, 2, 0], [10, 3, 0], [22, 12, 0]]
Recur Out: [[3, 2, 0, 10, 3, 0, 22, 12, 0]]
Iter. Out: [[10, 3, 0, 22, 12, 0], [3, 2, 0, 10, 3, 0]]
Iter2 Out: [[3, 2, 0, 10, 3, 0], [10, 3, 0, 22, 12, 0]]

# Results look ok, one nit: combos are coming out in different order
# (some append/insert issue somewhere i 'd say)
In: [[3, 1, 0], [3, 2, 0], [18, 0, 0]]
Recur Out: [[3, 1, 0, 18, 0, 0], [3, 2, 0, 18, 0, 0]]
Iter. Out: [[3, 2, 0, 18, 0, 0], [3, 1, 0, 18, 0, 0]]
Iter2 Out: [[3, 1, 0, 18, 0, 0], [3, 2, 0, 18, 0, 0]]
```

### Considerations

Focusing on the recursive solution, I am looking into few further cases:

1. What if "loops" appear in the SUB_NOUNS
2. What if we have some more SUB_NOUNS
3. How can we control list reuse in the proposed solution

For this I am using the following test:

```
SUB_NOUNS = {
    3: [10, 11, 18, 19, 20],
    10: [22, 30],
    # Third level. Note that we can have 10->22->30 and 10->30
    22: [30, 42],
    # Unhandled case where a larger number can be followed by a smaller number
    30: [1, 22],
}


test_list = [[3, 2, 0], [10, 3, 0], [22, 12, 0], [30, 0, 6], [42, 8, 9]]

print(f"\nIn: {test_list}")
print(f"Recur No Reuse: {get_all_combos(test_list)}")
print(f"Recur Reuse   : {get_all_combos(test_list, True)}")
```

Starting with the easy one: loops are avoided in the recursive solution by always processing lists from left to right and only *after* the current list (`data[list_num + 1:]`). This way we never go back and avoid infinite recursion. However, this is also a limitation to be kept in mind and the reason that the `SUB_NOUNS[30]` above will have no effect (since 1 or 22 will never appear in the input *after* 30)

With more SUB_NOUNS you have more "branches" and potential combinations. The output is:

```
In: [[3, 2, 0], [10, 3, 0], [22, 12, 0], [30, 0, 6], [42, 8, 9]]
Recur No Reuse: [
    [3, 2, 0, 10, 3, 0, 22, 12, 0, 30, 0, 6], 
    [3, 2, 0, 10, 3, 0, 22, 12, 0, 42, 8, 9], 
    [3, 2, 0, 10, 3, 0, 30, 0, 6],
]
Recur Reuse   : [
    [3, 2, 0, 10, 3, 0, 22, 12, 0, 30, 0, 6], 
    [3, 2, 0, 10, 3, 0, 22, 12, 0, 42, 8, 9], 
    [3, 2, 0, 10, 3, 0, 30, 0, 6], 
    [10, 3, 0, 22, 12, 0, 30, 0, 6], 
    [10, 3, 0, 22, 12, 0, 42, 8, 9], 
    [10, 3, 0, 30, 0, 6], 
    [22, 12, 0, 30, 0, 6], 
    [22, 12, 0, 42, 8, 9],
]
```

Notes - open-ended points:

- You can see in the above example how things can branch out and how both 10->30 and 10->22->30 combinations are considered
- You can also see double-branching: on the 10->22 path we have 10->22->30 and 10->22->42
- Notice that in the second invocation we set `allow_reuse=True` in `get_all_combos`. This allows the code to return combos whose first element/list has already participated in another combination. Altho in your `[[3, 2, 0], [10, 3, 0], [22, 12, 0]]` example you do not seem to look for such combos, they are all "correct" and follow the rules of SUB_NOUNS

As you said in the post, this might not be the best or a perfect solution but I believe recursion allows you to do all sorts of things which would be really hard otherwise in this particular case. I found this problem fairly complex due to the numerous possibilities of input data, constraining it a bit and narrowing down the scope if possible (ex. input always has up to 3 sub-lists) would help simplify the solution.

Comment: Wow thank you so much for your in depth answer. My pair_lists function has changed slightly as I did notice the error you spotted. I will post that as a seperate answer, but it wasn't that elegant. Your observations are all spot on, I completely agree with your point about recursion but could never get it working without the infinite loop problem. Yeah the plan is for the SUB_NOUNS to be much larger, however I'm trying to design it so that numbers are always followed by larger numbers. It's definitely proved a complex problem and constraining isn't possible, but this definitely works.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution with my method of correcting the error found in one of the example inputs, as @urban pointed out it's far from ideal, merely what I came up with after a few hours of pulling my hair out over this problem.

```
    def pair_lists(self, data):
        pairs = []  # Create an empty list to store the noun pairs
        combined = False  # Variable for checking if we need to join nouns
        for noun in reversed(data):  # Loop over the nouns in reverse
            try:
                result = itertools.filterfalse(lambda x: x[0] not in SUB_NOUNS[noun[0]],
                                               data)  # Filter out any that aren't sub_nouns
                for each in result:  # Loop the results
                    paired = []  # Make an empty list to pair them in to
                    if each not in paired:  # If the current iteration isn't in paired
                        paired.insert(0, each)  # insert it at index 0
                    paired.insert(0, noun)  # insert the noun at the start
                    chained = list(itertools.chain(*paired))  # chain them together
                    for pair in pairs:  # loop the pairs
                        if pair[:-3] == chained[3:]:  # if there is an intersection
                            pairs.remove(pair)  # remove the pair
                            pairs.insert(0, chained + pair[3:])  # then insert them joined
                            combined = True  # set combined to true
                    if not combined:  # if combined isn't true
                        pairs.append(chained)  # append the chained pairs
            except KeyError:
                pass
        return pairs if pairs else data
```